# PPA Error in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, ppa, repository

I am getting the following errors when I try to use a PPA:

```
~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs
[sudo] password for *****: 
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
FreeFileSync Releases
This is the official FreeFileSync repository for Ubuntu. It is recommended to use this to keep your FreeFileSync tool easily updated.

For instuctions on how to add the repository, see http://www.dlecan.com/archives/56-How-to-install-FreeFileSync-on-Ubuntu-PPA.html or (fr) http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/freefilesync.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~freefilesync/+archive/ffs
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 95, in run
self.add_ppa_signing_key(self.ppa_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in add_ppa_signing_key
print "Error reading %s: %s" % (lp_url, e[1])
NameError: global name 'lp_url' is not defined
```

how to fix it? I use Ubuntu 11.10.

Thanks

Comment: What does `lsb_release -a` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested the same PPA on a clean Ubuntu 11.10. I suggest you update your Ubuntu with any updates shown in Update Manager. The only changes I did were to add all the official repositories (multiver, universe...) and all 4 of the Update tab option (backport, restricted...)

A cause might be that the version of Python you are using is different from the one the system needs. I was going to upload an image but somehow imgur and askubuntu have a problem.

UPDATE - I FINALLY!!!! uploaded the image to imgur.

[image]

As you can see from this incredible and very patiently uploaded image, the PPA actually works. So like i suggested, first see if you have another PPA or have change the Python that comes by default with Ubuntu 11.10.